# Deploying alfresco on a different machine

Tags: deployment, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have installed Alfresco and have made the changes. How do I deploy it on the server so that the users can access it on the Internet?

I tried installing Alfresco on the other machine and copying the webapps folder so that the changes reflect on the new one. But the changes are not reflecting. How do I make sure that the changes are reflected on the other machine without doing it from scratch.

Comment: What kind of changes have you done on Alfresco?
Contents? Templates?
Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

For deploying an Alfresco installation on a different machine you should execute a cold backup from the source machine and a restore on the target of all the storage components:

- alf_data on file system
- Database
- Search indexes (Lucene or Solr)

Then you can copy all the application server files and configuration files on the target machine.

Remember also to update the alfresco-global.properties to change the references for the new file system and database restored from the cold backup.

Comment: I tried taking a backup and replacing the alf_data, postgresql, solr4 and tomcat directories in the new machine. I am able to see the changes I made on the login page. However, when I try to login I get an Authentication fail error. I have also tried changing the location in solrcore.properties in both the Solr spacesStores. I still get the same error and am unable to login.